# Upload a file (picture) to server with Laravel using FilePond, how?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, filepond

I'm trying to use [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) to upload profile picture during user registration on a Laravel 6 project.
In my `register.blade.php` I've a `<input type="file" id="profilePicture" name="profile_picture" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif">` then, at the botton of the file I wrote:

```
$('input[type="file"]').filepond();

FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        url: '/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    }
});
```

in `/routes/web.php` I added:

```
Route::post('/upload', 'FilepondController@upload');
```

and finally, for simplicity and only to check if the upload worked, in `/app/Http/Controllers/FilepondController.php` I wrote:

```
class FilepondController extends BaseController
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

but never the app dump $request and die... Obviously the upload via FilePont fail.

I tried to use [Sopamo/laravel-filepond](https://github.com/Sopamo/laravel-filepond) (Laravel FilePond Backend) too without success...

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you see the POST upload request in your browser developer tools' the network tab? Note that FilePond posts both the file as multipart form data and a json string (metadata attached to the file) under the same field name, in this case `profile_picture `

Comment: I solved the problem using Sopamo/laravel-filepond, there was an error in the upload controller included in that repo (it was `$file = $request->file('file')[0];` but I corrected in `$file = $request->files('filepond');` so now I need to publish the package to customize it, I tried `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Sopamo\LaravelFilepond\LaravelFilepondServiceProvider"` as written on GitHub repo but I get `Unable to locate publishable resources.`, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
FilePond.setOptions({
    server: '{{route('upload')}}',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [laravel-filepond by rahulhaque](https://github.com/rahulhaque/laravel-filepond) it's pretty well maintained, and easy to use of course.

```php
<script>
    // Set default FilePond options
    FilePond.setOptions({
        server: {
            url: "{{ config('filepond.server.url') }}",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ @csrf_token() }}",
            }
        }
    });

    // Create the FilePond instance
    FilePond.create(document.querySelector('yourhtml-file-input'));
</script>
```

```php
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'avatar' => Rule::filepond([
                'required',
                'image',
                'max:2000'
            ])
        ]);
    
        // Set filename
        $avatarName = 'avatar-' . auth()->id();
    
        // Move the file to permanent storage
        // Automatic file extension set
        $fileInfo = Filepond::field($request->avatar)
            ->moveTo('avatars/' . $avatarName);

        // dd($fileInfo);
        // [
        //     "id" => 1,
        //     "dirname" => "avatars",
        //     "basename" => "avatar-1.png",
        //     "extension" => "png",
        //     "filename" => "avatar-1",
        //     "location" => "avatars/avatar-1.png",
        //     "url" => "http://localhost/storage/avatars/avatar-1.png",
        // ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are laravel package available for the filepond might be useful for you

1. https://packagist.org/packages/cnviradiya/laravel-filepond

Easy to use upload file and you can get it in controller

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [putFile](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads) method on the Storage facade

> By default, the putFile method will generate a unique ID to serve as
>   the file name. The file's extension will be determined by examining
>   the file's MIME type. The path to the file will be returned by the
>   putFile method so you can store the path, including the generated file
>   name, in your database.

```
//...
$path = Storage::putFile('avatars', $request->file('profile_picture'));
$model->profile_picture = $path;
//...
```

You may also use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```